# TO_DATE in Oracle JDBC PreparedStatement giving invalid identifier

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am a bit baffled by this as I'm sure I have done it a hundred times but from this snippet of JDBC prepared statement:

```
"SELECT {0} FROM " +
                "(select a.* " +
                "from TABLE a " +
                "inner join TABLE p ON " +
                "and p.AS_OF_DT = TO_DATE(?, 'yyyyMMdd')";
...
    pStmt.setString(1, dateAsString);
```

I am getting

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "YYYYMMDD": invalid identifier
```

I can reproduce the error in TOAD by removing the quotes around YYYYMMDD.

**What do I need to do inside the prepared statement String to prevent this?**

I have tried

- playing with the upper/lowercase of YYYYMMDD
- Ensuring the dateAsString is in the right format
- Escaping the quotes like ''YYYYMMDD'' and '''YYYYMMDD'''

Comment: Can you show us the full SQL statement?

Comment: Not just the SQL statement, the full prepared statement code that generates the error.

Comment: Hi thanks for looking, I have now edited the code snippets to a more full representation

Comment: That isn't the actual statement that gets executed, for example, your `SELECT` clause seems to be templated. Please post the literal statement that gets executed. For all we know, the `SELECT` clause contains a `TO_DATE(somecolumn, yyyyMMdd)` (note the missing quotes)

Comment: You're right its something to do with the substitution. I can make it work by hardcoding that column clause Thanks.

Comment: Is the name of your table actually `TABLE`?